# Bootstrap 4 - How to add multiple headers with multiple columns per header?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I am working on an input form with multiple column headers across the top. Beneath each of the date headers (codepen below), there needs to be four columns. The only way I can seem to do this is by not using the `<tbody>`, and only playing in the `<thead>` space.

My question is whether or not this is the correct way to do this. If I add the columns in the `<tbody>`, it just aligns all the rows to the left, and not across the table.

Here's the **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/VdMxXp)**.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center name">Students</th>
      <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
      <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
      <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
      <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>
        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></th>       
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap, why use tables? Use the grid system that's built into it.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to do so. You can validate it with [w3-validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). However, it does not make sense. You could well use `tbody>tr>td`. I do not see any problem.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKGXBp

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark table-responsive">
      <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col" class="text-center name">Students</th>
       <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
       <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
       <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
       <th colspan="4" scope="col" class="text-center"><input class="form-control" type="date"></th>
     </tr>
      </thead>
          <tbody>
                 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>  
     </tr>
                 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>  
     </tr>
                 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>  
     </tr>
                 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>  
     </tr>
                 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="#"></td>  
     </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>   
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```